# ServiceStack Custom authentication class for User & Admin

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I was just looking for feedback on how to go about implementing this:

I have two types of users needing authentication in my system, Users & Admins. Now the tasks they will carry out and the data I store about them warrants that they each have a separate database table storing their info/authentication info.

I have implemented a working `CredentialsAuthProvider` called `UserCredentialsProvider` that authenticates users at `/auth/credentials`. The logic checks the `User` table in the database and authenticates. Now to authenticate Admins should I implement a second `CredentialsAuthProvider` called `AdminCredentialsAuthProvider` and register each on separate routes such as `/user/auth/credentials` and `/admin/auth/credentials` or also implement the admin logic within the same `TryAuthenticate` of `UserCredentialsProvider`.

If either above is the solution how would I go about registering separate routes or differentiating between admin/user when calling `TryAuthenticate`.

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick **with only one endpoint and one provider for authentication**. This will greatly simplify authentication.

Under the hood your auth provider needs to check both users and admins table. Once you have that I would translate all the data from both user and admin tables into one combined user resource. Admins should be denoted as users with the **"Admin" role**. That way you can still leverage built in Roles in ServiceStack.

In other words, I would sweep the complexity under some kind of data access layer so that your endpoints stay nice and clean.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a quick follow up on this. When I am submitting the login form json object containing the username/password I could also post along the role being requested i.e. admin/user. How in the tryAuthenticate method could I pass in the extra "role" contained in the request?

Comment: The TryAuthenticate method has access to the Request via authService.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>() so yes you can access any additional parameters there.